# Get last date of month of passed date

Tags: javascript, node.js, datetime, momentjs

- I have date like `2022-09-18T18:30:00Z`
- I want last date of the month
- I'm using below snippet

```
moment(`2022-09-18T18:30:00Z`).clone().endOf('month').utc()
```

I'm using Node.js and it's working in my local, but not in my live server. It doesn't gives me UTC time instead gave me `2022-09-30 23:59:59`

Comment: what exactly do you want to get? isn't that time the end of the month?

Comment: Yes that is ,but not in UTC
It should be `2022-09-30 18:29:59`

Comment: most likely your server's timezone (like most servers) is UTC.

Comment: Yes but then it should work ? It's not working

Comment: it's working because on the server, the end of month time is calculated at `2022-09-30 23:59:59` _in UTC_ and by calling `utc()` it doesn't change the value.

Comment: `.endOf('month')` will set the object to the end of the "local" month, i.e. based on the regional settings of the host system. Most servers are set to UTC, so *endOf* sets it to the end of the UTC month. So (per @technophyle's comment) `.utc` is redundant in that case. PS `.clone()` is superfluous.

Answer (score 1):

Without moment.js you can just set the UTC date to the last day of the month, e.g.

```js
let d = new Date('2022-09-18T18:30:00Z');

d.setUTCMonth(d.getUTCMonth() + 1, 0);

console.log(d.toISOString()); // 2022-09-30T18:30:00.000Z
```